# pouchdb testing emitted syncing state with mocking remoteDB

Tags: angular, jasmine, pouchdb

The test is an Angular 2 application with Jasmine.

I have this function that starts syncing with `remote DB` (one-way from Couchbase to PouchDB only). There are services that basically subscribe to an observable which is emitted on the replication event. Now I am being asked to test that the emitted syncing state is correct and deployment is blocked due to low test coverage on the service file.

So I call the `startSync` with the local `pouchdb` database and remote `couchdb` object. How can I possibly test that each event listener is emitting the right result? I have tried to go through the code of replicate.js but I am having no clue on it either. Any hint, please?

Basically I want to test the emitted state is "false" when I mock/generate the "error" event.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SyncingService {
  private subscription: any;
  public syncingState: any = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  private emitResult(state: boolean) {
    this.syncingState.next(state);
  }

  public startSync(localPouch: any, remoteDB: any, config: any) {
    let vm: any = this;

    this.subscription = localPouch.replicate
      .from(remoteDB, { live: true, retry: true })
      .on("paused", err => {
        vm.emitResult(false);
      })
      .on("active", info => {
        vm.emitResult(false);
      })
      .on("change", change => {
        vm.emitResult(true);

      })
      .on("error", error => {
        vm.emitResult(false);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like change the remoteDB to be invalid to trigger "paused" and throw in "paused" or "change" to trigger "error". I.e:

```
    this.subscription = localPouch.replicate
      .from("127.0.0.1", { live: true, retry: true })
      // bad server most likely gets paused with these flags
      .on("paused", err => {
        throw(new Error("oops")); // cause an unrecoverable error instead?
        vm.emitResult(false);
      })
      .on("active", info => {
        vm.emitResult(false);
      })
      .on("change", change => {
        vm.emitResult(true);

      })
      .on("error", error => {
        vm.emitResult(false);
      });
  }
}
```

active might be easiest to trigger by replicating from another localdb and adding to it while the replication is waiting for changes, updating a doc in the remoteDB would work too if it is allowed.